# Tag 'augustine' for Augustine orders?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag 'augustine' has in it's tag wiki: "Questions on works and thought St. Augustine of Hippo, an early Christian author, philosopher and theologian, and their reflections in doctrine of various denominations."

Now there is a question, tagged with 'augustine' about the Augustine Canons regular. I don't know if it is the only about the orders.

[Who were the Black Canons on the Augustinian Priory of Inchmahome in Scotland?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71372/who-were-the-black-canons-on-the-augustinian-priory-of-inchmahome-in-scotland)

Should questions about the Augustine Canons regular (CRSA) and the Augustines (OSA) be in the 'augustine' tag or should there be seperate tags for both or one common for both?

Comment: Tagging them with "augustine" doesn't make sense to me. But I'm not sure if a tag just for Augustine orders is necessary, or if they should just use the regular orders tag.

Comment: **Augustinian** makes more sense to me than **Augustine**.

Answer (score 1):

At present there does not exist a single tag for any Religious Order. There is no tags for either Benedictines, Dominicans, Franciscans, Carthusians or  Augustinians to say the least.

Do not believe it is necessary to have a Augustinian tag for this Order at all.

If we did have a tag for them it would be better to have it spelled **Augustinian** rather the **Augustine**.